# Webpack required variables out of scope

Tags: javascript, scope, webpack

I'm using Webpack to bundle my JavaScript together. Why is the colors variable unavailable from within the LineChart constructor?

```
// top of the file
var {colors} = require('../../global-config.js');
var a = 3; // colors is required correctly, and is available on this line 
// if I am stepping through the code.

var LineChart = function (svgElement, data, options) {
this.dates = []; // colors is unavailable at this point. Why?
```

At the end of the file:

```
module.exports = LineChart;
```

I can even require the variable from within the constructor, but I don't want to do that because I would have to require it in every function on `LineChart`'s prototype.

Comment: I think more details about your code will be needed to debug the issue. One thing which comes to mind is that the VM might be optimizing out the values available in the closure of the LineChart constructor if they are not being used at all in the function body. Hence, they may not show up in the debugger.

Comment: Can you set up a little demo project to study?

Comment: If you're viewing it in console - then it will be undefined unless it's used within the function. Are you saying that if you specify colors in the function - it comes out to be undefined?
If that's the case, then some more of your code/demo will be required